# Displaying a <dd> data before <dt>?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to display data in a DL where the dynamic DD data is listed before the DT.

Example: "3 Votes, 6 Comments" vs. "Votes 3, Comments 6".

```
<dl>
    <dt>Votes</dt>
    <dd>3</dd>
    <dt>Comments</dt>
    <dd>6</dd>
</dl>
```

A DL makes the most semantic sense; but without a parent-child relationship, I can't use floating.

Is there a way to make this work? Or is there a better semantic solution?

Answer (score 2):

As for myself, I would use simple list, something like this:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li data-n="1">Vote</li>
  <li data-n="6">Comment</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul { list-style: none; }
ul,li { margin: 0; display: inline-block; }
li:before { content: attr(data-n) " "; }
li:not([data-n="1"]):after { content: "s"; }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/5f94a6hx/)

And I think DL does not make semantic sence in this case, because it is not the definition of "Votes" and "Comments" terms

Comment: I like the solution, but my understanding the W3C spec around DLs is a little more flexible with their use than strictly for definitions.